# Unable to append a draggable element at exact coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dragging and dropping an element of class "item" into a droppable div with ID #inventory (position:relative)

My intention is to drop the .item element at specific coordinates and make its position absolute.

The droppable element has this code:

```
$('#inventory').droppable({
     // do something with the inventory $(this).doSomething();
     // do something with the draggable item $(ui.draggable).doSomething();

    drop: function(event, ui){      
        var item = ui.draggable;
        console.log("dropped");
        item.css({top: '50px', left: '50px', position:'absolute'});
        $('#inventory').append(item);       
    }


});
```

the dragable element code:

```
$('.item').draggable({  
    revert: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    drag: function(event,ui){
        var pos = ui.offset;
        console.log('X: ' + pos.left + ' ' + 'Y: ' + pos.top);
    }
});
```

However, the .item element never lands where I want it; it will always go to coordinates which are top: 0, left: 0 . But I noticed that the .css coordinates I set are actually used to start the animation from after I release the .item element on to the droppable area! Yes, when I drop the .item element, it travels to the upper left corner.

I am completely lost how to make the draggable element snap to the coordinates I want and stay there, I am sure I am missing something but cannot figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set revert to false?

```
$('.item').draggable({  
    revert: false,
    ...
});
```

as far as I know, it should be false because It is responsible to return the element to the start position when dragging stops.